# Adding a custom TypeAdapterFactory for Google GSON to detect use of annotations to return custom TypeAdapter dynamically

Tags: java, json, gson

Let us start with **sharing** working and **pastable** code (requires google gson package):

```
package mypackage;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

public final class ALL {
    static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new Factory()).create();

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface Serialize {}

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();

        String json = GSON.toJson(test);

        System.out.println(json);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final class Test {
        @Serialize
        String abc = "def";
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final class Factory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
        @Override
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            Serialize annotation = type.getRawType().getAnnotation(Serialize.class);

            boolean annotationPresent = type.getRawType().isAnnotationPresent(Serialize.class);

            Annotation[] annotations = type.getRawType().getAnnotations();

            if (annotationPresent) {
                System.out.println("11111111111111");
            }

            if (annotation != null) {
                return new Adapter<>();
            }

            return gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final class Adapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
        private static final java.util.Base64.Encoder ENCODER = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();
        private static final java.util.Base64.Decoder DECODER = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();

        @Override
        public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();
            String a = in.nextString();
            in.endObject();

            try {
                return deserialize( DECODER.decode(a) );
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
            out.value( encode(serialize(value)) );
        }

        private String encode(byte[] serialize) {
            return ENCODER.encodeToString( serialize );
        }

        private byte[] serialize(T value) throws IOException {
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(out); ) {
                os.writeObject(value);
                return out.toByteArray();
            }
        }

        private T deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in); ) {
                return (T) is.readObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we look at `Test` class, the goal is to output something else if the annotation `@Serialize` is present. In this case we output bytes in String. And when we then read this back, we would like to deserialize it.

Other ways of understanding **the goal** is to think of maybe using an annotation you would like to encrypt a value and you could decrypt it on readback.

This should be possible, no?

I know i can register TypeAdapters based on field type, however, I would like to be able to use annotations to declare intent instead.

No **wrapper** classes. You can create a custom **JsonSerializer** but this requires registering.

In the example above, the `type.getRawType().getAnnotation(Serialize.class);` is always returning null and `Annotation[] annotations = type.getRawType().getAnnotations()` always empty, so unable to detect using the factory.

Unsure how to detect the annotation dynamically.

Do you know?

Comment: I think that one problem is that you expect type to tell if there is an annotation for a _field_ of that type. It might work if there was an annotation on that types class declaration but that is not the case with String or your class Test.

Comment: pirho yes, but i am not really out after declaring it on the class since i might not even have access to it or desire to custom annotate it just for google gson. I am able to get around it now, although not ideally using: \@JsonAdapter(PathToAdapter.class) String abc = "def"; .. So basically ideally and for some reason internal google gson is able to detect \@JsonAdapter as well as exclusion annotations, but for some reason not my custom ones. Implementation for @JsonAdapter usage is in JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory ... but unsure what is different. My factory is kind of similar.

Comment: Yes of course it is possible but I think that the logic that Gson uses to parse **fields** is not exposed directly. Maybe overriding some classes in the Gson code is an option

Comment: Did you check how it is done in Gson source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using @JsonAdapter? You anyway need to know how to do de-/crypting and need to implement tha per type. For string in your case, for example:

```
public class CryptoAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
        out.jsonValue(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.reverse(value));
    }
    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.reverse(in.nextString());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Test {
    @JsonAdapter(CryptoAdapter.class)
    String abc = "def";
}
```

The problem is that Gson does not provide (to my knowledge) any direct means to create some own field processor that lets user to read the **field/class member** annotations.

In other words you need an access to the **field** during de-/serialization and that seem not to be possible in an easy way.

That is why there is this `@JsonAdapter`.

If interested to study more clone [source code from GitHub](https://github.com/google/gson.git) and check:

```
public final class ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory
```

Unfortunately `final`. There is a method named `createBoundField` (which I think is the logic behind recognizing `@JsonAdapter` for **fields**) and the path and overriding that logic is not so straightforward.

For classes there seems to be solution quite similar to yours:

```
public final class JsonAdapterAnnotationTypeAdapterFactory
    implements TypeAdapterFactory
```

Both above mentioned are added to the list of `TypeAdapterFactories` when a new `Gson` is created.

Comment: Yes, I just commented a few minutes ago on your comment regarding this. But I still don't understand why @JsonAdapter is detectable but not mine. Wierd, but I guess the best thing one can do.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/269 ... implementation provided, although not ideal: https://github.com/amaksoft/gson/commit/b264334451c487d79241483103853c3fff27cbd4